# Changing InnoDB to MyIsam in Backup file okay?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, innodb, myisam, iso-8859-1

Hi i got a SQL Backup File and i noticed that my Mysql Server is configured to use utf8 and innodb by default when importing or making new tables.

When i installed my script in the sql file in each table the engine was specified as myisam and charset latin.
So the basic tables from the cms are in latin1 and myisam.

Now i installed some plugins and tables by plugins are importet as innodb and utf8.

i now manually changed the engine and charset from innodb/utf8 to myisam/latin1 in my backup file and reimportet it.

The import was possible without any problems and it seems that everything works BUT the question:

can i always replace "Engine=Innodb" with "Engine=MyIsam" without any issus?

Comment: There won't be data integrity issues. The two engines work very differently when it comes to querying, though. Stuff like transactions, row locking, crash recovery, etc. are all better in InnoDB and you really should be using it. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam

Comment: Thanks for the info that it is okay to convert innodb tables to myisam.
Now i am calm. :)

Comment: I did not say it's OK. I said the data should at least carry over. There are vanishingly few scenarios where you *want* MyISAM in 2017.

Comment: data carry over = it (script) works, right?
I know that innodb is might better but the script has been designed for older php mysql versions originally i just use it locally.

Comment: No, scripts might not necessarily work right. For example, InnoDB doesn't have `FULLTEXT` indexes, so if your app relies on one that'd break. If your app needs transactions, switching everything to MyISAM would break that. You might see horrible performance because of MyISAM's shitty locking.

Comment: So as long as i do not use Fulltext and No InnoDB only feature it should work? because thats given.

Comment: Work? Yes. Good idea? Not really. Time to ditch MyISAM was years ago. Why are you determined to keep it?

Comment: I just use the script locally its over 10 years old. :)

Comment: AFAIK, @Michael_'s comment about FULLTEXT indexes is no longer correct. Mariadb/Mysql have had fulltext indexes since release 10.0.5/5.6.4.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a problem.  Assuming the backup was create by `mysqldump` or the like, it is a text file in which you can verify the following.

The dump has baked into it the `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` for each column.  This overrides the "default" for tables.

Any `CREATE TABLE` you do can be done one of two ways:

- Explicitly specify the charset on each column.
- Explicitly specify the charset on the table; this will propagate to the columns.
- Do neither, in which case, you get the new default (which it sounds like you don't want).

As for changing the `ENGINE=` clause, there are a small number of rare differences.  But the easy thing is to change it and see if you get any errors.

- Very old dumps may say `TYPE=` instead of `ENGINE=`; change that.
- MyISAM allowed a 2-column primary key with the *second* column to be `AUTO_INCREMENT`; InnoDB does not have that feature.
- MyISAM does not handle `FOREIGN KEYs`; their definitions will be ignored.

More on converting from MyISAM to InnoDB:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

It is a bad idea to regress from InnoDB to MyISAM.

Yes, you can change the charset on tables, then import.  *But*, the load needs to specify the charset of the bytes in the dump, not the charset for the tables you will be loading into.  (The conversion will be done for you if needed.)